# How to change Chromium configs through extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I need some advice about Chromium extension possibilities. Can the extension change configs of the browser such as: home page, default behavior for protocol handlers (tel, mailto), security settings ("protect from dangerous websites" for example), disable sending statistics to Google, etc.?

**Which configs from `chrome://settings/` can be changed and how to do it if it's possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Chrome API index](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) is a good place to start.

From it, you can glean the following capabilities:

- [`accessibilityFeatures` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/accessibilityFeatures) that deals with accessibility settings.
- [`browsingData` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData) that deals with clearing browsing data.
- [`contentSettings` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings) that deals with allowed content, site permissions and plugins.
- [`downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) can at least partially influence download settings.
- [`fontSettings` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fontSettings) can manage fonts used by Chrome.
- [`management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) can manage (but not install) other extensions.
- [`privacy` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/privacy) deals with privacy-related settings (that includes some security settings).
- [`proxy` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) can manage proxy settings.

In addition, there's a lot of Chrome OS specific APIs I won't list here.

There are also some manifest keys that can influence Chrome settings on install - such as the home page. See [`chrome_settings_overrides`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) (note: not available on Linux) and to a lesser extent [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

See also [Protecting user settings on Windows with the new Settings API](https://blog.chromium.org/2014/03/protecting-user-settings-on-windows.html) (which announced the above).

Other than those, no, you can't override Chrome settings. You cannot *dynamically* change the home or search provider, you can't control protocol handlers (that's on OS level anyway), etc.

Note that you can't inject scripts into `chrome://*` pages, so you won't be able to just fiddle with the UI.