# Is there any api or launch arguments to change Chrome download dir?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and I want to change Chrome download dir.

I searched the api list and Chrome launch arguments list but failed to find any info.

Comment: The downloads API allows to specify a relative directory path within the download folder. There's [no](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) command line switch.

Comment: but if I want to change to a totally different folder?@wOxxOm

Comment: So what? You're out of luck, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No API and launch arguments.
Finally I modify the Preferences file in profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is indeed no such API.

You can control a sub-path into the Download folder with `chrome.downloads` API, but that's about it.

[Not many Chrome settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729856/how-to-change-chromium-configs-through-extension/45731097#45731097) are exposed to extensions.

Comment: I find that webdriver can change download folder with Chrome options, do you have any idea about their implementation? It seems that they overwrite the Preferences file.